# All asm labels becoming symbols in executable file

Tags: assembly, linker, x86, nasm, elf

When assembling an object using `nasm`, I'm finding that all labels are included as symbols in the resultant `.o` file, as well as the final binary.

This makes sense for function entry points that I've declared `GLOBAL`, and for section start parts (e.g., for the `.text` section), but it seems odd that labels simply used as loop entry points and such all near to appear in the output file. In addition to leaking internal implementation details, it wastes space in the symbol table.

For example, given this short assembly program:

```
GLOBAL _start
_start:
    xor eax, eax
normal_label:
    xor eax, eax
.local_label:
    xor eax, eax
    xor edi, edi
    mov eax, 231    ;  exit(0)
    syscall
```

... built using:

```
nasm -f elf64 label-test.s
ld label-test.o -o label-test
```

Results in `l` (i.e., local) symbols in both the object file and linked executable:

```
objdump --syms label-test.o

label-test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 label-test.s
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000002 l       .text  0000000000000000 normal_label
0000000000000004 l       .text  0000000000000000 normal_label.local_label
0000000000000000 g       .text  0000000000000000 _start
```

Note that both `normal_label` and the local label `local_label` ended up in the symbol table. All of them end up in the symbol table of the executable also.

I don't want to emit these symbols to the final executable. Can I tell nasm not to include them? There are some options I could pass to `ld`, such as `--strip-all`, which will remove those symbols, but also *every other* symbol in the executable. That makes it quite the cudgel: it eliminates the symbols I really want to keep for readable stack traces, debugging, etc.

---

FWIW, as mentioned by Peter Cordes, `yasm` doesn't have exactly the same issue. With an elf64 `.o` file built in exactly the same way as above (but with `yasm` substituted for `nasm`, we get:

```
objdump --syms label-test-yasm.o 

label-test-yasm.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 label-test.s
0000000000000004 l       .text  0000000000000000 
0000000000000002 l       .text  0000000000000000 
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 g       .text  0000000000000000 _start
```

The global `_start` label is still included, but the other two labels aren't named - they are still there though, they are the unnamed symbols at offset 4 and 2 (lines 2 and 3 in the list above). This is confirmed by adding more labels - more unnammed symbols are produced.

Comment: yasm doesn't do that by default.  (It does if you use `-gdwarf2`)

Comment: Huh, yeah. So maybe it's a bit of a nasm quirk. I added that to the bottom of the question. You mention the `-g` stuff and it occurred to me these are added primary for debugging, but it's worth noting that `--strip-debug` on the `ld` command doesn't remove those (or any symbols) on the binaries built by nasm.

Comment: Well I googled harder this time and it seems like it might just be a [limitation in nasm](https://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=1951.0).

Comment: I'd always assumed there must be some way (like stripping after the fact) to deal with this issue when using NASM itself (rather than YASM), but it sounds like that might not be the case.

Comment: Yeah you can strip after the fact, see my answer below. Still, I'd prefer the yasm approach of not having to deal with it in the first place. Perhaps I'm asking for too much though, e.g., I may want "function labels" to be left in the file (e.g,. for stack traces), but for internal jmp targets like loop tops and conditionals to be stripped, but there isn't a formal distinction between the two.

Comment: Right, I meant I assumed there was some way to get rid of just the `.` labels, leaving the non-`.` labels.  i.e. I assumed that nasm would have some way to accomplish what yasm does (since it's obviously useful), but hadn't bothered to look since I usually just use yasm.

Comment: Correction on yasm, it does add entries to the symbol table, but they are "unnamed". Details added above.

Comment: @PeterCordes - good point about global vs local in the sense of `normal_label` vs `normal_label.local_label` above (call it label-global and label-local). Mostly I was using "locally" a bit loosely - both in that sense (nasm/yasm local labels) and in the `ld` sense of local `l` and global `g` symbols (i.e., the change the `GLOBAL` directive makes in the asm). Neither `yasm` nor `nasm` seem to treat label-global/local any differently in terms of linkage.

Comment: That's odd that yasm makes empty-string symbol-table entries.  In practice, though, you get the desired behaviour: `objdump -d` disassembly output is broken up into functions, not with breaks for `.` labels inside functions.  As far as I'm concerned, that's and debugging are the main reasons to care about this.  Not wasting symbol table size would be nice, I guess, but is generally fine.

Comment: Good point about `objdump -d` output. Despite not being marked as `f` (function) in the elf output, objdump annoyingly breaks up the disassembly by each of the labels, as you point out. For unnamed labels it doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, it's just a limitation in nasm. See for example [this forum post](https://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=1951.0) where the poster has approximately the same issue (although 32-bit rather than 64-bit ELF), and no solution is provided other than using a stripping tool.

In my case, it seems stripping the object file like:

```
strip --discard-all label-test.o
```

should do the trick. Despite the name of the `--discard-all` option, it only strips local symbols and leaves global symbols alone. Here's the symbol table before stripping the file:

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 label-test.s
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000002 l       .text  0000000000000000 normal_label
0000000000000004 l       .text  0000000000000000 normal_label.local_label
0000000000000000 g       .text  0000000000000000 _start
```

and after:

```
SYMBOL TABLE:
0000000000000000 l    df *ABS*  0000000000000000 label-test.s
0000000000000000 l    d  .text  0000000000000000 .text
0000000000000000 g       .text  0000000000000000 _start
```

Note in particular that it was smart enough to leave the `.text` section symbol alone, even though it is local. Of course this strip option can't really distinguish between useless (loop label) and potentially useful symbols, for example local function entry points which are needed to give correct stack traces with various tools.

If you wanted to be smarter about it, you could selectively strip only the asm-local (i.e., labels starting with a `.`) using the `--wildcard` and `--strip-symbol` options to selectively strip only labels with an embedded `.`.

I'm still looking for a better answer if one is lurking out there.

Answer (score 2):

A little late, but I had this problem and wrote a patch for nasm 2.15 that fixes this. It adds a command-line switch called —discard-labels. You can get it here:  https://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=2666.0

Comment: Thanks! I'm interested in the nasm-DWARF work you've done on Linux that you mention in that post. Anywhere I can read more about it?

Comment: Hi there BeeOnRope, I have a BASIC Compiler I’m working on here: https://github.com/clockworkdevstudio/idlewild-lang . But it’s really experimental, not even alpha. Only the Linux version will even build at the moment. All the DWARF stuff is located in three different files, Compiler.hs, Semantics.hs and DWARF.hs.