# objdump format for a function written in C vs asm

Tags: c, assembly, objdump

Consider the following C code:

```
void zero_c(char* buffer, int bytes) {
  for (int i = 0; i < bytes; ++i) {
    *buffer = 0;
    ++buffer;
  }
}
```

And the following assembly code:

```
global zero_asm

segment .text
zero_asm:
  cmp rsi, 0x0
  jle end
  xor rax, rax
  mov rax, rdi
  add rax, rsi
me: 
  mov BYTE [rdi], 0x0
  inc rdi
  cmp rdi, rax
  jne me
end:
  ret
```

I put both these functions in a single binary, and looking at the assembly via objdump. Here is the output.

```
00000000004009b0 <zero_c(char*, int)>:
  4009b0:       85 f6                   test   esi,esi
  4009b2:       7e 17                   jle    4009cb <zero_c(char*, int)+0x1b>
  4009b4:       8d 46 ff                lea    eax,[rsi-0x1]
  4009b7:       48 8d 44 07 01          lea    rax,[rdi+rax*1+0x1]
  4009bc:       0f 1f 40 00             nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]
  4009c0:       c6 07 00                mov    BYTE PTR [rdi],0x0
  4009c3:       48 ff c7                inc    rdi
  4009c6:       48 39 c7                cmp    rdi,rax
  4009c9:       75 f5                   jne    4009c0 <zero_c(char*, int)+0x10>
  4009cb:       c3                      ret    
  4009cc:       0f 1f 40 00             nop    DWORD PTR [rax+0x0]

00000000004009d0 <zero_asm>:
  4009d0:       48 83 fe 00             cmp    rsi,0x0
  4009d4:       7e 14                   jle    4009ea <end>
  4009d6:       48 31 c0                xor    rax,rax
  4009d9:       48 89 f8                mov    rax,rdi
  4009dc:       48 01 f0                add    rax,rsi

00000000004009df <me>:
  4009df:       c6 07 00                mov    BYTE PTR [rdi],0x0
  4009e2:       48 ff c7                inc    rdi
  4009e5:       48 39 c7                cmp    rdi,rax
  4009e8:       75 f5                   jne    4009df <me>

00000000004009ea <end>:
  4009ea:       c3                      ret    
  4009eb:       0f 1f 44 00 00          nop    DWORD PTR [rax+rax*1+0x0]
```

As you can see, objdump shows C function in one big blob, whereas shows the asm function that I had written in three sections. Is there a way in which I can write my assembly that it shows up as only one blob as C function does. (I am using nasm assembler to compile my assembly)

Comment: Why do you care? The cpu doesn't. It's just `objdump` formatting the output by breaking at the labels.

Comment: The only difference seems to be that objdump inserts a blank line before each of your labels (`me`, `end`).  The [code generated by gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/9v9FMj) uses the GNU assembler's [local symbols](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html#Symbol-Names) feature, where symbols starting with `.L` are not included as symbols in the object file.

Comment: Apparently you can't tell `nasm` not to put all symbols into the table. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39653210/547981).

Comment: @Jester It is an idle curiosity, but you can imagine that <me> and <end> are just local symbols and shouldn't come in `nm` output. (currently they are visible). And thanks for linking that question!

Comment: @NateEldredge that makes sense. Coupled with the question which jester shared, I think that explain everything.

Comment: I am then going to close as duplicate.